# Javascript take script server side

Tags: asp.net, javascript

How can I take this code

```
<script>
var arr = [<%= myArray %>+<%= my2Array %>]; 
var sorted_arr = arr.sort(); 
var results = []; 
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i += 1) { 
        if (sorted_arr[i + 1] == sorted_arr[i]) { 
                results.push(sorted_arr[i]); 
        } 
} 
 document.write(results +"<br />");
</script>
```

and convert it to <% the above script %> and keep the functionality?

Why does the script work in the script tag but not when I place it in <% %>

```
    <%
var arr = [myArray+my2Array]; 
var sorted_arr = arr.sort(); 
var results = []; 
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i += 1) { 
        if (sorted_arr[i + 1] == sorted_arr[i]) { 
                results.push(sorted_arr[i]); 
        } 
} 
%>
<%= results %>
```

If I use it like this the results are returned as empty

I suspect the reason why it is not working is because the results value is not getting populates... In the script version it gets the time to populate and loop

Comment: Server side scripts are not written in javascript. What's the language you are using to write server scripts?

Comment: I am using asp and javascript

Comment: What do myArray and my2Array contain? - are they JScript arrays? I don't think you can just add them

Comment: It is text values - myArray and my2Array = 'this','is','a','test'

Comment: If those are ASP arrays, simply outputting them into the page won't work the way you expect.  You'll need to have some ASP code loop over each array and echo the variables - so that when the page is sent to the client, it parses as valid JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run your code server side you need to change the line

```
var arr = [myArray+my2Array];
```

to

```
var arr = (myArray+','+my2Array).split(',');
```

Comment: var arr = (myArray+my2Array).split(',');  
var sorted_arr = arr.sort();
var results = [];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i += 1) { 
        if (sorted_arr[i + 1] == sorted_arr[i]) { 
                results.push(sorted_arr[i]); 
        } 
 
} 

Works 100% thanks meouw!